# Emacs column mode from one file to another: Register does not contain text

Tags: emacs, copy

I am trying to copy a column from a text file to another with emacs.
I select the text with `C-x, r, r`, and then try to copy the same in another text with `C-x,r,l + Enter`. However, at the end it says: `Register does not contain text`. Is it because I am trying to copy from one file to another?

Comment: Just trying to confirm, after selecting the text and pressing `C-x r r` emacs prompts for register, right? Also use `insert-register` bound to `C-x r g` to insert the copied text.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean... I select the text with the mouse, then `C-x r r` and it appears `Copy rectangle to register`. Then I press `Enter`. The second sentence is completely obscure to me.

Comment: OK sorry for not being clear. Press `C-x, r, g, <enter>` to paste the copied text. `C-x r l` runs a different command. I will elaborate this in an answer.

Comment: Np. If I try your way, after `C-x, r, g` it says `Insert register:`, the I press `Enter`, but then I receive the usual error `Register does not contain text`.

Comment: What did you do to copy the text. I am assuming you selected the text, then pressed `C-x, r, r, <enter>`, am I right? If not what was the exact sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball suggests that maybe you're copying from two different Emacs sessions.  Registers only work within a single Emacs session.

Comment: What does your crystal ball mean by Emacs sessions?

Comment: It probably means "an Emacs process".  If you start Emacs twice, you get two sessions.  If you start Emacs once and then use `C-x C-f` (for example) various times to open several files, you get a single Emacs session which visits several files.